# Changing the Facebook associated Page of a Facebook Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

A few days ago a new option appeared in my Facebook groups. To create a Facebook Page and link it with the Facebook Group. I tried it to see what it was about, and in the cover of the Facebook Group they added a link to the Facebook Page created. Now I want to change that page, but I don't see the option anywhere. I already had a Facebook Page of the same topic of the Facebook Group with 8700+ fans so I don't want to waste it. Is it possible to change the associated page of a Facebook Group?

Comment: vinculate? What's that?

Comment: sorry, I guess I was thinking in spanish. It's linked in several parts of the group. 1- The page becomes admin of the group 2- The page gets a link in the cover 3- The page gets another link and the icon at the right of the group 4 - The group gets a link in the Facebook page.

Comment: I guess the word I was looking for was "associated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found an answer for this just by chance. I was trying to change the linked page of a Facebook group from the group settings. I'm not sure if it can be done from there because I couldn't find an option, from the group you can create a page to associate to the group, but I don't see where the page can be changed from the group. But from a Facebook page, you can choose a group to associate the page to. This option doesn't appear in any page, it could be because it's a new feature, or it could be because it's available only to certain type of Facebook pages (I've done this twice for Facebook pages of businesses), but in those which appears, it appears in the timeline of the Facebook page if you are an admin of the Facebook page.

My guess it's you have to be admin of both the Facebook page and the Facebook group, since the page will also appear as an administrator of the Facebook group.

Comment: Can you be more specific, screenshots would be very appreciated, where this option is available?